# Magento 2 How can I filter orders to see all but completed?

Tags: magento2, filter, order-status

Google is useless. Is there a way to view the orders in M2 and exclude those that have been completed? I know I can filter by all of the statuses, but I cannot find a way to view all but those that have a status of "complete".

Comment: Filter on admin grid or in a custom coded collection?

Comment: Dominic, I do not know what you mean.